# Is there any way to modify Android Text To Speech pronunciation?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am looking a way to develop an app in Android which speaks Javanese Language from texts. As I know there is no such Javanese TTS installed by default. So is there any way to modify default TTS engine pronunciation? 
For example, the my expected pronunciation of "PIYE" is pee-ye. Here is what the TTS engine produces:

`mTts.speak("piye", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null); // output: pie-ee`

Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the pronunciation. There is not API method to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do something similar - get an app to use standard US-EN pronunciation for scientific terms. My solution is to force the TTS engine to say certain words in a certain way by first replacing them with phonetically correct phrases. Here's an example:

myString = myString.replace(" cis "," sihs ");

This approach seems promising but not perfect.